# Getting a Notes Dateime from a ViewEntry into a JAVA Date

Tags: java, datetime, xpages

I have this block of code in a Java Method:

```
colVal = ve.getColumnValues();
    System.out.println("Got colVal");
    System.out.println("Col values = " + colVal.toString());
    try {
        Document pDoc = ve.getDocument();
        System.out.println("Start MyDate");
        DateTime dt = (DateTime) pDoc.getItemValueDateTimeArray("ExpPayDate").get(0);
        Date pDate = dt.toJavaDate();
        pItem.setMyDate(pDate);
    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // date error
    System.out.println("setMyDate Failed "+ e.toString());
    }
```

The log looks like this:

```
12/09/2015 02:49:59 PM  HTTP JVM: Got colVal
12/09/2015 02:49:59 PM  HTTP JVM: Col values = [1bp8frg61ze9s, 24/09/2015 12:00:00 PM MDT, , 0.0, ---, , --- No Agent ---, , ]
```

I use the ViewEntry because I need to maintain the view sort order. 
The problem with this is that the `ve.getDocument()` means an extra trip to the server and is could become fairly expensive.
So I have tried to work just with the colVal.get(1), it is viewed as a Notes DataTime but colVal.get(1).toJavaDate() does not seem to be available.

Changed the code to try to get the value from the colVal:

```
System.out.println("Got colVal");
System.out.println("Col values = " + colVal.toString());
    try {
     System.out.println("Start MyDate");
    System.out.println("Get value from colVal " + colVal.get(1).toString());
                        //pItem.setMyDate(pDate);
    } catch (Exception e)
        System.out.println("setExpPayDate Failed "  + e.toString());
}
```

When I run this "get value from colVal " causes an error :

```
12/09/2015 03:05:55 PM  HTTP JVM: Start MyDate
12/09/2015 03:05:55 PM  HTTP JVM: setMyDate Failed java.lang.ClassCastException: lotus.domino.local.DateTime incompatible with java.lang.String
```

I can do what I need from the document but can't seem to get there from the viewEntry and the ve.getColumnValues().

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The immediate solution is that you need to cast the object to a `DateTime` to be able to call the `toJavaDate` method. For example:

```
DateTime dt = (DateTime)colVal.get(1);
Date date = dt.toJavaDate();
```

This is because the `Vector` returned by `getColumnValues` returns `Object`-typed values, since it can be mixed.

In this specific case, there's also a way to get the column value as a `Date` directly. If you call `entry.setPreferJavaDates(true)` before getting the column values, then date/time values will be represented as `Date` objects instead of `DateTime`. You'd still probably end up casting the column value to `Date` anyway, but that can be a small convenience. It also eliminates the need to do `entry.recycle(colVal)` inside the loop to make sure the `DateTime`s in the column values are recycled.

Comment: Jesse -- that did it thanks. This is a code snippet:

ViewEntryCollection veCol = vwPayment.getAllEntriesByKey(lKey);

while (ve != null){
ViewEntry tVE = ve;
colVal = ve.getColumnValues();
ve.setPreferJavaDates(true);
PaymentItem pItem = new PaymentItem();
colVal = ve.getColumnValues();
Date dt = (Date) ve.getColumnValues().get(1);
pItem.setExpPayDate(dt);
pItem.setContract(colVal.get(7).toString());
.........
Utils.recycleObjects(pItem,ve);
ve = veCol.getNextEntry(tVE);

}

veCol.recycle();

Is there anything else that needs to be recycled? As you said I should not need to recycle colVal.

Comment: I think that recycling the view entry should come after fetching the next one, shouldn't it? Though if it works as-is, maybe not. I also don't imagine pItem needs recycling there - recycling is a Notes-object-specific thing due to their C-side handles.

Comment: I use this structure all the time. 
tVE = ve;
do my stuff;
ve.recycle();
ve = veCol.getNextEntry(tVE);

is there a better way to do that?

Comment: Nah, if it works, no reason to change it - I'd have thought there'd be an "object has been removed or recycled" exception, but it seems I was mistaken.